# Populate FilteringSelect from a json file

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have a json object(say dobject) returning data from a json file

Here is snippet of the json:

```
"FormR": [
            {
                "limit": 2,
                "no": "One"
            }, {
                "limit": 2,
                "no": "Two"
            }
        ],
```

now i want to create a FilteringSelect which should have **One** and **Two** when the dropdown is selected. Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, one idea : http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect#programmatic-example-using-a-dojo-store

Comment: Thanks...i implemented the filtering select and i can see it on the page but i am unable to set the values that should be displayed from the json file....here is what i tried var rs1 = new dojo.store.JsonRest({target:"form2/"});
            var ds1 = new dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: rs1});

            var fs = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({name: "FormR", placeHolder: "Select a number", store: ds1}, "Select"); how do i set the values of the dropdown to One and Two(FormR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to tell the select which field to use as an identifier. Second you need set value for the filtering select.
In your case, the code is something like:

```
 var rs1 = new dojo.store.JsonRest({
    target:"form2/",
    idProperty: "no"
 });
 ...
 var fs = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    value: 'One'
    name: "FormR", 
    placeHolder: "Select a number", 
    store: ds1
 });
```

Comment: Actually the right attribute in dojo.store.JsonRest for the id is called "idProperty", not "idAttribute" (at least in 1.7). See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store.html#properties

Comment: Hello Chris thank you...I tried the same...I can see an error in firebug saying: Unable to load form2/One... @Philippe thank you ..i even tried with idProperty and the result is same...what might be the reason?

Comment: It looks like you have set the wrong target on your JsonRest. The error means the URL resolved does not exist. Try to fix the url by looking at what firebug gives you...

Comment: hi...i am using dojo 1.6 is it making any difference? refer--http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/FilteringSelect-and-MemoryStore-td3246019.html

Comment: @user1257271, for dojo 1.6, the store dojox.data.JsonRestStore, and it uses idAttribute to indicate id field.